# PHP loop increment

Tags: php

I have a PHP loop generating a dataset for a chart. It queries two fields I have in a database table.

```
<?php

    $server = "myserver:1234";
    $user="dbuser";
    $password="userpass";  
    $database = "dbname";

    $connection = mysql_connect($server,$user,$password);
    $db = mysql_select_db($database,$connection);

    $query = "SELECT X, Y FROM dbtable";
    $result = mysql_query($query);        

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $dataset1[] = array($row['X'],$row['Y']);
    }
    $final = json_encode($dataset1,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);

?>
```

Currently data in `X` is meaningless (it's actually an `ID` column), and a number increment of 1 starting at 1 will be more useful. This is because I only want to plot a line chart, where X values are fixed. `ID` would be fine but the values put distracting axis labels on my chart.

How can I use PHP to generate this instead of the database select that I currently have?

Many thanks:)

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I got that expression from somewhere else online. I'm not a developer per say, what should I be using instead? I'm not being lazy, I just struggle to follow heavy documentation.

Comment: Have a look at the PDO tutorial (last link in my previous comment).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare a variable outside your loop and increment it on each iteration:

```
$i = 1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $dataset1[] = array($i, $row['Y']);
    $i++;
}
```